# Using make to execute independent tasks in parallel

Tags: unix, shell, makefile, buildfarm

I have a bunch of commands I would like to execute in parallel. The commands are nearly identical. They can be expected to take about the same time, and can run completely independently. They may look like:

```
command -n 1 > log.1
command -n 2 > log.2
command -n 3 > log.3
...
command -n 4096 > log.4096
```

I could launch all of them in parallel in a shell script, but the system would try to load more than strictly necessary to keep the CPU(s) busy (each task takes 100% of one core until it has finished). This would cause the disk to thrash and make the whole thing slower than a less greedy approach to execution.

The best approach is probably to keep about `n` tasks executing, where `n` is the number of available cores.

I am keen not to reinvent the wheel. This problem has already been solved in the Unix `make` program (when used with the `-j n` option). I was wondering if perhaps it was possible to write generic Makefile rules for the above, so as to avoid the linear-size Makefile that would look like:

```
all: log.1 log.2 ...
log.1:
        command -n 1 > log.1
log.2:
        command -n 2 > log.2
...
```

If the best solution is not to use `make` but another program/utility, I am open to that as long as the dependencies are reasonable (`make` was very good in this regard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [pattern rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Pattern-Rules.html)

Another way, if this is the single reason why you need `make`, is to use `-n` and `-P` options of `xargs`.

Comment: `echo {1..1024} | xargs -n 1 -P 4 echo` giving `1 3 2 5 4 ...` (bash 3) seems about what I want. I did not think about it at the time, but I may also write `n` sequential scripts for slices `1`..`N/n`, `N/n+1`..`2N/n`, ... as long as the slices average out to the same time (it's not a given).

Answer (score 4):

Here is more portable shell code that does not depend on brace expansion:

> LOGS := $(shell seq 1 1024)

Note the use of := to define a more efficient variable: the simply expanded "flavor".

Answer (score 3):

First the easy part. As Roman Cheplyaka points out, pattern rules are very useful:

```
LOGS = log.1 log.2 ... log.4096
all: $(LOGS)

log.%:
    command -n $* > log.$*
```

The tricky part is creating that list, `LOGS`. Make isn't very good at handling numbers. The best way is probably to call on the shell. (You may have to adjust this script for your shell-- shell scripting isn't my strongest subject.)

```
NUM_LOGS = 4096

LOGS = $(shell for ((i=1 ; i<=$(NUM_LOGS) ; ++i)) ;  do  echo log.$$i ; done)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Bash 3 has the pattern `{1..1024}` that can probably be taken advantage of for the second part.

Answer (score 3):

xargs -P is the "standard" way to do this.
Note depending on disk I/O you may want to limit to spindles rather than cores.
If you do want to limit to cores note the new nproc command in recent coreutils.

Comment: In my case I could fit the entire inputs and outputs of the tasks in a ramdisk if I needed to, but thanks for introducing me to the notion of "spindle".

Answer (score 2):

With GNU Parallel you would write:

```
parallel command -n {} ">" log.{} ::: {1..4096}
```

10 second installation:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

Learn more: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1